# Jquery realTime charting without comet

Tags: jquery, ajax, charts, comet

Is there a way to use realtime ajax charts with Jquery without having to set up a comet server ?
i've seen some pluging claiming to be realtime but at the end they just use `setTimeout()`.
thoughts ?

i only need the chart to update once there's a change in the server , not every second or such .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see doing this is with long polling or websockets. Without websockets, there's no concept of server-initiated updates and you're back to comet or other long-polling architectures.

Comment: okay thanks .. i'm checking out on Nodejs  i wonder if it's the right way to go . i'm working on a php project .

Comment: Best of luck! I couldn't really say if Nodejs is good match for a primarily PHP project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the ability to pusher updates from you PHP app without the hassle of installing a Comet or WebSocket server, or the hassle of trying to do this within PHP then a [hosted realtime service](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide#hosted-services) may be the solution.

To use such a service you simply embed JavaScript in your app which connects the web browser to the service and whenever you want to push an update you make a call to a RESTful API to trigger the update event.

In your scenario whenever new information should be draw in a chart you push this information from the server by making a call to the REST API. The hosted realtime service then pushes this update to all connected clients. The JavaScript within the client then needs to interact with the Chart plugin and update the drawn chart.

Comment: thanks the information you provided is very helpful , nevertheless i think that in this early stage of the project i'm working on , we don't expect too much traffic , i guess it would be wise enough to postpone the long polling and substitute it with setinterval.
i'll try different solution as experiments for now .. thank you